# Why doesn't JS work inside React Native returned code?

Tags: react-native

I have the code below but for some reason the variable is not declared inside the returned code(it says underscore in vs code) and before the return code the variable is declared well. Why is that?

[image: screen]

```
export default function App() {

    {const age = 18}  // This code work    

    return (
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>

        {const name = "Mike"}  // This code doesn't work

        <StatusBar style="auto" />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx), everything inside `{}` in JSX must be a valid [JavaScript expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#expressions). The statement `const name = 'Mike'` is not an expression since it does not resolve to a value.